# Substitute BatchNorm with Conditional BatchNorm in torchvision ResNet

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I have an instance of `torchvision.models.ResNet` and I have my class `CondBatchNorm2d` that is a module similar to `BatchNorm2d` but the forward method accepts an additional input `y` that does not come from the previous layer since it is an input of the whole network:

```
    def forward(self, x, y=None):
...
```

I know how to substitute each `BatchNorm2d` instance with an instance of `CondBatchNorm2d` but I am not sure how to write my own forward method to include the new input for intermediate `CondBatchNorm2d` layers. Should I iterate in the forward on the resnet children or is there a more suitable way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hackish, assuming

> it is the input of the whole network

you might create a new model wrapping conditional `CondBatchNorm`:

```
class FedCondBatchNorm2d:
    def __init__(self, y, *args, **kwargs):
        self.batch_norm = CondBatchNorm2d(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cond_img = y

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.batch_norm(x, self.cond_img)
```

As its API is now the same as original Reset you might simply switch blocks via `module.apply`